# AWS RDS MySQL DB unable to connect in MySQL workbench and could not connect using telnet

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I am using default VPC and created RDS MySQL instance (Publicly Accessible: Yes) with newly created db security group. I have given Inbound/Outbound rules as All Traffic, ALL, ALL, and Source = 0.0.0.0/0 and used this security group for MySQL DB instance.

I have disabled Windows Firewall.
Still I cannot connect to my DB End point using hostname and port 3306 via telnet and MySQL Workbench.
In MySQL Workbench, I'm getting 10060 error and telnet says Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306, connect faild.

What is still missing?

Comment: 10060 is `WSAETIMEDOUT` ("Connection timed out.")  Does the RDS instance's subnet have the igw-xxxxxxxx "Internet Gateway" object as it's default route (in the VPC console)?  Where are you connecting from? Outside, on the Internet, I assume?  Could there be a firewall on your Internet connection that is blocking you?

Comment: There are 3 subnets attached to RDS instance, all have Route table as rtb-424c1827 having 2 rows,   Destination=172.31.0.0/16 Target=local & Destination=0.0.0.0/0 Target=igw-054cc760.  Network ACL: acl-6b72300e having Inbound rules as  Rule#100, ALL Traffic, ALL, ALL, 0.0.0.0/0, ALLOW And Rule#*, ALL Traffic, ALL, ALL, 0.0.0.0/0, DENY.   Same is for Outbound Rule.

Comment: I have disabled Windows Firewall, and I'm connecting from laptop over internet.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot problem is resolved, port number 3306 was blocked so I used different port and now I am able to connect from outside. Thanks anyways.